# Styling shadow DOM with external

Tags: css, html, shadow-dom

Given a webpage with dynamically loaded web components (shadow DOM) and some external CSS files (Bootstrap, etc.). I want these CSS files to be applied within the components (shadow DOM). What are the possible solutions?

- Using Polymer -- we're already using AngularJS and don't wanna start messing with another framework too. (Although it's possible.)
- Refactoring the CSS files and include `/deep/` everywhere -- maintainability...
- Import each CSS file manually into the beginning `<style>` part of each shadow DOM -- no comment...

Is there any better way to apply whole CSS files within shadow DOMs?

Comment: I asked a very similar question to this once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document

Comment: In this case the dataflow is done by AngularJS. But the modular yet consistent styling is still an issue. Thx anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is a bit old, but putting this answer here in case it helps.

1. /deep/ has been [deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120)
2. Other option is to use [custom properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details) provided by Polymer.

If you don't want to use Polymer then as suggested in the [discussion](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489954#c12) on the /deep/ and ::shadow selectors deprecation thread, you can you use css @imports.
You can generate the url of your external stylesheet and inject it in your shadow dom templates at run-time.
I have written a descriptive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32941101/4788782) on the topic.