# Placeholder with asterisk mark having different color

Tags: html, css

I am stuck with this issue - I want to give a place-holder text a different color and the asterisk mark different color, I am using following code

CSS

```
input[type=text] {
    &.required{
        &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
                &:before{ content: '*'; color:@pink; vertical-align: top; font-size: small; } 
        }
        &:-moz-placeholder:after {
                &:before{ content: '*'; color:@pink; vertical-align: top; font-size: small; } 
        }

        &::-moz-placeholder:after {
                &:before{ content: '*'; color:@pink; vertical-align: top; font-size: small; } 
        }

        &:-ms-input-placeholder:after {
                &:before{ content: '*'; color:@pink; vertical-align: top; font-size: small; } 
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input placeholder="Adresse courriel" type="email" id="edit-submitted-adresse-courriel" name="submitted[adresse_courriel]" size="60" class="form-text form-email required">
```

This worked before only on chrome but now without making any changes it stopped working.

Condition: I cannot add `<span>` inside input as its webform can't add html tags for placeholder.

Hoping to get some solution

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217144/css-pseudo-element-input-placeholderafter-to-show-with-or-without-value-in-tex
Seems to not work anymore in latest Chrome versions

Comment: Ok thanks Vincent Will check this

Comment: @nikita any luck you got this fixed?