# change only the asterisk in placeholder to red

Tags: placeholder

I am having trouble with a placeholder. I would like to change the color of the asterisk inside of the placeholder to red and leave the rest the dim black.

I am using bootstrap .form-control for markup. [image]

I would like to know if there is a plugin/easy method of doing this. 
JS or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any easy way to have 2 colors in a place holder.

You can try adding an asterisk after your placeholder using `-webkit-input-placeholder::after`, and change its color, but this solution does not work in all browsers: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217144/css-pseudo-element-input-placeholderafter-to-show-with-or-without-value-in-tex)

You can try something like this and add your placeholder as a label...

```css
input[required] + label {
    position: relative;
    left: -170px; /* move the label left and place it inside the input */
    color: #757575; /* placeholder color here */
}

input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" required="required" />
<label for="myInput">IME IN PRIIMEK</label>
```

Comment: thanks for this! was hoping for a more solid option but this will do just fine!

Comment: Asterisk is not hidden while typing the content in text :(