# How do I add a red asterisk in the placeholder?

Tags: html, css

I was building a form with questions in the placeholder.
Now I want a red asterisk for the required fields.
Normally we could use `span` for giving different styles to the asterisk, but in my case, I can't add `span` in the placeholder.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 520px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 90px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: #333;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #777;
}

.btn-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form1">
    <h2>Let's Start Building!</h2>
    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

    <div class="btn-box">
      <button class="BN" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://paulund.co.uk/add-required-asterisk-with-css
Is there a way can use this website's method in my code?

Comment: Welcome! At Stack Overflow, it's very helpful to explain what you already tried and why that didn't work. You did mention something that might work, but it doesn't look like you explained why it didn't work, or what about that solution was difficult or confusing. That would be very helpful in answering your question.

Comment: I mention the above, because it looks like what you posted in the link _should_ solve your question. Therefore, it would be nice to know what you tried and why that did not work... (Posting broken code that you expected to work but didn't is a great way to illustrate this)

Comment: You don't have that much control.  You don't really want that in the placeholder anyway, do you?  Don't you want the red asterisk visible even after they've started typing?

Comment: Ohh... yeah, I tried the link but that did not work out. I posted that link cause I thought there could be some way out by tweaking the code according to my form's code.  And as I'm new to it, I couldn't do it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah that's a good idea, but how do we do this?

Comment: You use a `<span>` just outside of the `<input>` box, which you said you already know how to do, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS pseudo-element input-placeholder::after to show with or without value in text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217144/css-pseudo-element-input-placeholderafter-to-show-with-or-without-value-in-tex)

Comment: It looks like the link you posted has a mistake: [`:after` is not really supported for text inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)

Comment: @SuhaibAhmed Are you ready to use jquery to solve this? If you want I will post an answer.

Comment: Looks like `::placeholder:after` used to work (based on [this example](https://codepen.io/rlacorne/pen/mlvJt/) existing), but no longer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can probably safely assume the reason why OP (aka **O**riginal **P**oster) won't use a `<span>` is because `<input>` has `width: 100%`. Whenever an `display: inline` (ie `<span>`) or `inline-block` proceeds an element that has `width: 100%`, that element is forced to occupy the space underneath the preceding element of `width: 100%`.

### Simply decrease the `width` of the `<input>` and use a `<span>`

**Demo A** is exactly like OP's demo with the exception of the `<input>` having `width: 90%` and a `<span class='asterisk'>*</span>` proceeding it.

**Demo B** and **Demo C** are improved versions that:

- uses [semantic elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) like `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`.
- has some ineffective styles removed.
- has the `<div class="btn-box">` removed.
- has altered `margin`s, `padding`, `text-align`, and `font-size` that are ascetically better IMO.
- has the property `type='button'` removed. See ***`<button>` in a `<form>`*** section below.

In addition **Demo B** uses the following to display an asterisk:

- A `<label>` instead of a `<span>` for semantics's sake.

In addition **Demo C** uses the following to display an asterisk:

- The CSS property [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) is assigned to the `<fieldset>` element instead of actually using an extra element like a `<label>` or `<span>` used in the previous demos.

**Note:** In all demos a special character was used for the actual asterisk called [*"combining asterisk above"*](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/combining%20asterisk%20above). This character appears at the top of the line much like a super-scripted character.

**Also Note:** The `font-size`s are absolute values (`px`) which I would not normally use but the OP's demo is not responsive.

### `<button>` in a `<form>`

A `<button>` within a `<form>` has inherit behavior when the user clicks it, the `<form>` will [validate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) according to whatever applicable instructions are set within the HTML or JavaScript then if everything is proper it submits the data. If a `<button>` has `type="button"`, that `<button>` doesn't do anything without JavaScript which means the HTML property `required` is limited to validating user input by showing a message when `<input>` is hovered on.

In **Demo B** and **Demo C** the `<button>` does not have `type="button"`. Enter something that is ***not*** an email address and compare the behavior to **Demo A**. When a valid e-mail address is entered in **Demo B** or **Demo C**, the entered data disappears which means it was submitted (of course it doesn't have any JavaScript so it just submits to nowhere).

### Demo A

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 520px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 90px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: #333;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

form input {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.asterisk {
  font-size: 3ch;
  color: red;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #777;
}

.btn-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form1">
    <h2>Let's Start Building!</h2>
    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
    <span class='asterisk'>⃰</span>

    <div class="btn-box">
      <button class="BN" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Demo B

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 520px;
  padding: 90px 0;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

form {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form * {
  font-size: 18px;
}


fieldset {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.asterisk {
  font-size: 3ch;
  color: red;
  cursor: help;
}

legend {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  color: #333;
}

input {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}


::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.next {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <form>

    <fieldset>

      <legend>Let's Start Building!</legend>

      <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
      
      <label class='asterisk' title='           E-mail is required    '>*</label>

    </fieldset>
    
    <button class="next">Next</button>

  </form>
</section>
```

### Demo C

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 520px;
  padding: 90px 0;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

form {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form * {
  font-size: 18px;
}


fieldset {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.required::after {
  content: '*';
  font-size: 22px;
  color: red;
}

legend {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  color: #333;
}

input {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}


::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.next {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <form>

    <fieldset class='required'>

      <legend>Let's Start Building!</legend>

      <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

    </fieldset>
    
    <button class="next">Next</button>

  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!
Also, helped me understand new things.

Comment: What's better B or C?

Comment: Also, can you pls explain to me why <fieldset> and <legend>?
I'm new to this

Comment: And what if my demo was responsive?
What changes can be made for that?

Comment: All valid questions which I'll answer briefly: 1. B is more HTML. C is more CSS. but both get the job done. 2. They are [semantic elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics). 3.  99% of all length values would be relative (ex. `%`, `em`, `vw`, etc) not absolute (ex. `px`). Other factors like layout and media queries must also be considered as well, refer to this article on [Responsive Design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design).

Answer (score 2):

This is not ideal, but since you said you can't add elements and didn't mention using JS, I tried a css only solution...again, not an ideal situation. I don't know what happens before or after this page. I added the asterisk using a `::before` on the div containing the button and setting it to be `position:relative`, while the asterisk is set as `position:absolute` and moved next to the input field. I'm ready for the pitchforks and torches.

```css
/*---------------------------------*/

input[type="email"][required]+.btn-box::before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  left: -10px;
}

input[type="email"][required]+.btn-box {
  position: relative;
}


/*---------------------------------*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 520px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 90px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: #333;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #777;
}

.btn-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form1">
    <h2>Let's Start Building!</h2>
    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

    <div class="btn-box">
      <button class="BN" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
what if I can add more elements or use JS? Can it be more ideal?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible for you to add to your HTML, a label associated with the input would be helpful, see for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

> Associating a  with an  element offers some major advantages:
>
> The label text is not only visually associated with its corresponding
> text input; it is programmatically associated with it too. This means
> that, for example, a screen reader will read out the label when the
> user is focused on the form input, making it easier for an assistive
> technology user to understand what data should be entered. You can
> click the associated label to focus/activate the input, as well as the
> input itself. This increased hit area provides an advantage to anyone
> trying to activate the input, including those using a touch-screen
> device.

It remains after the placeholder has disappeared so the user is reminded what is needed, and you can format it. For example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(/assets/1.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 520px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 8% auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 90px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: #333;
}

.container form {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
label[for="email"]::after {
  content: ' (required)';
  color: red;  
}
input[required] {
  border: solid red;
}
 ::placeholder {
  color: #777;
}

.btn-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form1">
    <h2>Let's Start Building!</h2>
    <label for="email">Please type in your email address</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

    <div class="btn-box">
      <button class="BN" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```