# Register a mouseover event on a <datalist>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I'm starting to experiment with javascript/jquery and I have an input field with a datalist attached to it. The only problem I have is that when i "hover" over the datalist (once it appears) I want to trigger an event.

I have managed to trigger click and change events, but mouseover just won't work and I can't seem to find an example that works. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){ 
        // This works
        $("#browserList").on("change", function(){
            console.log("changed val=" + $(this).val());
        });

        // This does not 
        $("datalist#browsers").mouseover(function(){
            console.log("hovered");
        });

    });

</script>
```

```
<input list="browsers" id="browserList" placeholder="Find a browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option>Explorer</option>
    <option>Firefox</option>
</datalist>
```

Please tell me what I am missing,
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mouse over use the below syntax

```
$("#browserList").mouseover(function(){
  //do something
})
```

If you want to trigger the event on options of datalist, it's not possible because they are shadow elements. please see [the  explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894243/get-current-value-from-datalist-onhover) from another SO question. This explains better about it.

Comment: Thank you for that, mouseover was of course the event I wanted. I have edited the question. Unfortunately that does not solve my problem. Yes it triggers an event when I'm hovering over the actual input field. But I want it to trigger when I hover over one of the options.

Comment: @Johan Well!! ohkay I updated my answer for it!! it's not possible !!

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll try to find another solution then.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, this is not possible with a select either? It seems like it isn't.

Comment: @Johan so any solution you found or nothing ?

Comment: no unfortunately, tried moreless the same thing using a <select> instead, same result.

Comment: @Johan yup!! as the link says,events can't be attached on shadow elements