# Get AM/PM from HTML time input

Tags: javascript, html

First, I know that `<input type="time">` is not supported by IE10 or earlier, and Firefox, but this is only for testing purposes and I will make appropriate, cross-browser changes at another time.

For the time being, I have a HTML time input field. I am trying to extract the values from it including the hour, minutes and AM/PM. I can display the hour and minutes, but an AM/PM indication is not including.

I have an input as follows:

`<input type="time" name="end-time" id="end-time">`

I print out via `alert()` the input value as follows:

`alert(document.getElementById('end-time').value);`

Upon input I receive an alert such as:

`01:34`.

Notice that an AM/PM is not included in the `alert()`.

How can I get the AM/PM value from a HTML time input via Javascript?

Comment: The returned result is in the form of a 24 hour clock, not a 12 hour clock. If you want the time with AM & PM, check the first two values, and  utilize something like the following: `if(FirstTwoNums > 12){ FirstTwoNums -= 12; PM = true;}/*else, PM is false */`. There might be a better way, but you can use `parseInt` after you split the time value string to get the hour value as an integer; thus allowing it to be used in the aforementioned conditional.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as i know, We cannot get the value from the input directly in the meridian format of 'AM/PM'. Instead, we can write our own logic of converting the value in the AM/PM format and store/display it.

Below is the implementation of it.

```js
var inputEle = document.getElementById('timeInput');


function onTimeChange() {
  var timeSplit = inputEle.value.split(':'),
    hours,
    minutes,
    meridian;
  hours = timeSplit[0];
  minutes = timeSplit[1];
  if (hours > 12) {
    meridian = 'PM';
    hours -= 12;
  } else if (hours < 12) {
    meridian = 'AM';
    if (hours == 0) {
      hours = 12;
    }
  } else {
    meridian = 'PM';
  }
  alert(hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + meridian);
}
```

```html
<input type="time" onchange="onTimeChange()" id="timeInput" />
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
function print() {
  var [h, m] = document.getElementById('time').value.split(":");
  console.log((h % 12 ? h % 12 : 12) + ":" + m, h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM');
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="time">
<button onclick="print()">Submit</button>
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `document.getElementById('end-time').valueAsDate` which gives you a new Date() with the correct time. From there you can get the hours using `.getHours()` (0-23) and minutes using `.getMinutes()` (0-59). See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for more about JavaScript Dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix for date AND time.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<title>12 hour Time and Date stamp</title>
<meta name="" content="">
<script>
///////////
///////// DATE generator    /////////
function date_time(id){
        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
        d = date.getDate();
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
        h = date.getHours();
        if(h<10){h = "0"+h;}
      m = date.getMinutes();
        if(m<10){m = "0"+m;}
       s = date.getSeconds();
        if(s<10){s = "0"+s;}
       result = ''+days[day]+' '+months[month]+' '+d+' '+year;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
        return true;
}
///////// end DATE Generator /////////
//////////////////////////////////////
/////////// Time Generator ///////////
function tS(){ x=new Date(); x.setTime(x.getTime()); return x; } 
function lZ(x){ return (x>9)?x:'0'+x; } 
function tH(x){ if(x==0){ x=12; } return (x>12)?x-=12:x; } 
function dT(){ if(fr==0){ fr=1; document.write('<font size=3 face=Arial><b><span id="tP">'+eval(oT)+'</span></b></font>'); } document.getElementById('tP').innerHTML=eval(oT); setTimeout('dT()',1000); } 
function aP(x){ return (x>11)?'pm':'am'; } 
var fr=0,oT="' '+tH(tS().getHours())+':'+lZ(tS().getMinutes())+':'+lZ(tS().getSeconds())+' '+aP(tS().getHours())";
///////// end Time Generator /////////
/////////
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Date.. Easily adjustable with javascript Array-->
<p><span id="date_time"></span></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script><!--this MUST be included for Date-->
<!--Time in 12 hour format-->
<p><span id="dT"><script language="JavaScript">window.onload = dT('dT');</script></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used this for over 6 years. ALWAYS works. But a couple notes:
    1: For the time, adjust the CSS from within the Javascript.
    2:Adjust display text (jan,Feb,march... mon,tues,wed,etc...) By changing           values within Date Generator Section.  
You can see this working at [AutoRoXX Network](http://autodude666.com/network)

Hopefully this code snip will help you with what you are trying to accomplish. 
I HATE seeing people struggle :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do not believe accessing `.shadowRoot` of native `<input>` elements using `DOM` methods is currently possible. Where, at chromium, chrome the element

```
<span 
  role="spinbutton" 
  aria-valuetext="blank" 
  aria-valuemin="1" 
  aria-valuemax="2" 
  aria-help="AM/PM" 
  pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field">
--
</span>
```

having `.innerHTML` of `AM` or `PM` is rendered at `<input type="time">` element `.shadowRoot` at `change` event of element. See [Is it possible to access Shadow DOM elements through the parent document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document).

Have not found a workaround to select the elements within the `.shadowRoot` of `DOM` ` element,

You can use `input.valueAsDate.getTime()`, which is incremented in values of `3600000`, where is value is less than `43200000` the time is `"AM"`, else `"PM"`; format the output by checking if first two digits of `.value` is greater than or equal to `13`, if true replace first two digits of `.value` string with value of an object having property names ranging from `13` through `23`

```js
var times = {}, re = /^\d+(?=:)/;

for (var i = 13, n = 1; i < 24; i++, n++) {
  times[i] = n < 10 ? "0" + n : n
}

document.getElementById("end-time")
.onchange = function() {
  var time = this
  , value = time.value
  , match = value.match(re)[0];
  this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML =
  (match && match >= 13 ? value.replace(re, times[match]) : value)
  + (time.valueAsDate.getTime() < 43200000 ? " AM" : " PM")
}
```

```html
<input type="time" name="end-time" id="end-time">
<label for="end-time"></label>
```