# How to get two input (type time) values with (am/pm) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in javascript I'm trying to get input value.

The alert only shows time(10:10) not with am or pm.
but I'm trying to print (10:10 am)

```js
function calculateTime() {

  var start = $('#startTime').val();
  var start = $('#endTime').val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="startTime" name="startTime">
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endtTime" onchange="calculateTime()">
```

Comment: So where is the code that adds the am/pm?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310579/get-am-pm-from-html-time-input

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the code you tried

Comment: sir, i  get time with am/pm both inputs in one function

function calculateTime() {

  var start = $('#startTime').val();
  var start = $('#endTime').val();
}

Comment: <input type="time" class="form-control" id="startTime" name="startTime">
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endtTime" onchange="calculateTime()">