# how do I traverse elements within a shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I have

```
div id=outer
  #shadowRoot
    div id=inner
    button
```

In the click handler of the button, I want to reference the div "inner". In a non shadowDom world, this would be `document.getElementById('inner')`, but what is the equivalent in a shadow DOM world?

NB. This is accessing from within the custom-element. I am not trying to pierce the shadow DOM from outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access Shadow DOM elements through the parent document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document)

Comment: Rather than access through the parent document, I was trying to access from an event within the shadowRoot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the absolute path: use `shadowRoot` to get the Shadow DOM content.

```
document.querySelector( 'div#outer' ).shadowRoot.querySelector( 'div#inner' )
```

Or the relative path: use `getRootNode()` to get the Shadow DOM root

```
event.target.getRootNode().querySelector( 'div#inner' )
```

Example:

```js
outer.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    .innerHTML = `
        <div id=inner></div>
        <button>clicked</button>
    `
    
outer.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'button' ).onclick = ev =>
  ev.target.getRootNode().querySelector( 'div#inner' ).innerHTML = 'clicked'
```

```html
<div id=outer></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, it was specifically the `getRootNode()` that I was looking for. Many thanks.