# Is it possible to read a shadowRoot with JQLite (angular.element)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to reach/read some elements, which are inside a shadow-root, in my case a *form* tag. The HTML structure of the web-component seems like this:

```
<web-comp>
  <h1>Titel</h1>
  #shadow-root (open)
     <form>
         ...
     </form>
</web-comp>
```

Inside the Angular directive's link function i have sth. like:

```
link: function ($scope, el) {
  var myWebComponent = el.find("web-comp");  // it finds it
  var titel = myWebComponent.find("h1");     // it finds it too

  myWebComponent.find("form");          // does not find it
  myWebComponent.find("shadowRoot");    // does not find it
  myWebComponent.find("#shadowRoot");   // does not find it
  myWebComponent.find("#shadow-root");  // does not find it
  myWebComponent.shadowRoot;            // does not find it
  myWebComponent.#shadowRoot;           // does not find it
}
```

Is there a way to reach to form tag inside the shadowRoot?

Comment: PD - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document

Comment: thanks, but my question is about JQLite..

Comment: The [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite)   `.find` method is limited to lookups by tag name.

Comment: @georgeawg if you know that it is not possible with jqlite, you can write that also as an answer..