# Get element of controls (scrubber) of a video element in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-video

When generating a standard video object in HTML5 you can activate standard controls for it. When using an inspect tool of a browser I see that the element I am looking for is called a scrubber, which is the timeline that shows where the video is standing at (and start and end position). My browser says that this element is named input#scrubber.scrubber . How can it be accessed through javascript? I need to get its starting and ending x positions, which should not be a problem once I can get the element.
I tried document.getElementsByClassName and document.querySelectorAll to search for it but somehow did it wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Want to know what minute the video is in? You could use the currentTime method for this, but if you want to identify this in a percentage way, just use the duration method and the current time method and get the quotient between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's part of the browser's Shadow DOM / pseudo-elements. You can't access them by javascript - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document).