# Feature-detect a calendar picker in <input type=date>

Tags: html, date, input, calendar, picker

I want to use the browser default calendar picker for my `type=date` input control. I'm happy with how it looks on Chrome and Opera. Safari technically "supports" `type=date`, however, right now all it gives me is the little up/down arrows, which is not useful. IE10 doesn't have any sort of helpful picker.

How do I avoid using browser detection to give a fallback calendar picker to browsers that don't have a picker?

I can feature-detect support for `type=date`, but that means that browsers like Safari which technically support it won't get the fallback calendar picker.

Is there a way to specifically detect the picker itself, instead of `date` support?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718456/check-if-browser-supports-html5-timepicker