# How can you detect input type="time" on firefox os

Tags: firefox-os

You can see [Modernizr #1030](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1030) for more of a background, but essentially Firefox OS returns `type: text` on `<input type="time">` elements.

It seems like it is the result of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910551), but the cause of the bug hasn't been found as of the time of this post.

Is there any way to properly detect input type="time"?

Comment: Which version of Firefox OS are you using? Getting the type of time inputs works for me in Gecko 29.

Comment: This question was asked while using FFOS 1.1

Comment: IIRC the fix landed in Gecko 26 / FXOS 1.2.

Comment: great to hear, I will test and confirm. That being said, I would still like to know if there is a way to detect this in >1.2

Comment: I can confirm it was fixed in 1.2, it would be great to find a way to detect it <=1.1, though

Answer (score 0):

A tip has been given on an another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025102/detect-browsers-native-date-time-pickers) :

```
function isDateSupported() {
  var i = document.createElement("input");
  i.setAttribute("type", "date");
  return i.type !== "text";
}
```

Comment: Appreciated, but as mentioned above, Firefox os returns type as text, so this answer isn't accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
yourDOMNode.getAttribute('type') === 'time'
```

Works for me on the browser of Firefox OS 1.1 (lg fireweb).

Here is a very ugly example I've assembled quickly to test (typed on my iPad keyboard, sorry): http://jsfiddle.net/Bh2pw/7/

The first button returns text while the second returns time.

Comment: edit: actually, this doesn't work. This just returns what you have set as the type. try setting the input type to 'faketype' and getAttribute  will return type as 'faketype'.

Comment: I see, so you are trying to detect support for input type time in the browser, and not if a particular input is of type time, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Yeah, this is a Firefox OS specific question, sorry for not making that clearer!